# Unable to delete .apk file

Tags: apk, files, delete

I downloaded a ROM file on my Google Pixel 3a XL and it left behind an APK file with the name of the game.

[image]

I am now unable to delete the file. When I try to, it just has a pop-up saying 'couldn't delete 1 file'.

If someone could please advise as I'm worried about having this file.

Comment: You are on Android 10?

Answer (score 2):

You could try rebooting your phone and deleting the file.  It's possible that a running app or service has that file handle open and won't let you delete it for that reason.

It's also possible that maybe the file is already deleted, it's just your app that you're using to view the file that needs to be refreshed.  It can't delete a file that doesn't exist.

You could also use [TotalCommander](https://apkpure.com/total-commander-file-manager/com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander) to delete the file.

If that doesn't work, you can always plug your phone up to your computer and use ADB.

```
adb shell rm "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Mario Party 7.apk"
```

(replace `/storage/emulated/0/Download` with actual file path)